# Uneven white lines around PDF in Adobe Acrobat

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-acrobat

I have created an image in photoshop, then flattened the image and saved as a PDF. OPened the PDF in Acrobat in order to add hyperlinks. My client wants to send this image out digitally with hyperlinks.

But when I open in Acrobat there are en even white lines around the border. WhenI saves and opens in another program they are still there.

I am not sure why they are there or how to get rid of them, please help.

I have tried cropping the image on acrobat but the white lines show back up. not sure what is going on here.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have an incrementally small rotation on your background fill, and it doesn't "go all the way" to or past your art board or document borders, resulting in this slightly rotated white, which is the whitespace behind your background.

1. Correct your rotation issue, just to have things correct.
2. Extend your background out beyond the edges of your artboard or document (this is called a bleed) before exporting out your PDF.

Answer (score 0):

Open Photoshop, flatten layers together: black background, frame around image, image part. All the rest can stay the same. It is glitch of rendering of vector objects. You can rid of them in Acrobat also, but as default settings will always be different, if you need to show this on different computers, it's better to flatten objects.
Keep in mind that flattening will use same resolution as it is set to your image before flattening.